# smarty replace line breaks

Tags: php, smarty

At the time of writing this, the smarty.net website appears to be down.

Anyway, how do I replace line breaks with a space in a smarty variable?  Is it something like this `{$var|regex_replace:'[\\r\\n]':'\s'}` ?   I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Define "it didn't work".

Comment: Smarty.net - Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to smarty.net .   My regex - linebreaks still exists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this if it works:

```
{$var|regex_replace:"/[\r\n]/" : " "}
```

Comment: It may help some one: In my case there were 2 line breaks (perhaps Paragraph marks), So i find the solution {$var|regex_replace:"/[\r\t\n][\r\t\n]/":""} here:http://grokbase.com/p/php/php-smarty-general/02bw8zmv2z/smarty-need-modifier-to-break-up-paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

The problem with [\r\n] is that it'll replace a single windows crlf with a double replacement.  (this is not a biggie if you just output spaces, but...)

Example:

```
{$letter="--\n--\r\n--\r\n\r\n--"}
{$var|regex_replace:"/[\r\n]/":"BR"}
result:
--BR--BRBR--BRBRBRBR--
```

Consider if you want to replace line breaks with html newlines; the above will create a mess.  This is what works as expected:

```
{$var|regex_replace:"/\r*\n/":"<br>"}
```

(Btw; if you consider nl2br for the above; it won't replace newlines, it'll just add a br to each - that can be a problem in some cases)

Now, the classic mac newline is just a carriage return, so more tweaking would be needed for that, but it's probably not really existent anymore.