# Unexpected new line Javascript/Smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty, prestashop

I'm developing a Prestashop website, and I'm getting a "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" javascript error.
The problem is when I get an address, this works nice:

```
,"address1":"Pza libertad"
,"address2":"4&ordm; 3&ordf;"
,"postcode":"08905"
```

The problem comes here:

```
    ,"address1":"Plaza libertad 3"
    ,"address2":"
4&ordm;3&ordf;"
    ,"postcode":"08905"
```

This code is generated like this:

```
{foreach from=$type.formated_fields_values key=pattern_name item=field_name name=inv_loop}
{if !$smarty.foreach.inv_loop.first},{/if}"{$pattern_name}":"{$field_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"
{/foreach}
```

In the database, the two "address2" looks the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: in address2's value is a line-break, as like html-escaping you also need to escape line-breaks to \n... i don't have smarty, but read about [escape](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl) there is also a 'javascript' argument

Comment: Thank you, I changed the 'htmlall' argument to 'javascript' but it's still doing the line break.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078804/smarty-replace-line-breaks

Comment: Still not working :(
Actually I can't understand why is putting a line break right there if it's not in the database.

Comment: Now it's working!! I've used this:
    {($field_name|regex_replace:"/[\r\n]/" : " ")|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}